# How to create table with Simple.Data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, create-table, simple.data

I'm making my first steps with `Simple.Data ORM`. I wanted to know if there is anyway I can create new table in my database. Currently I'm working on `MemoryAdapter` (provided with library) but in future, I want to do the same with production database.
So far, I've tried with `Simple.Data.RawSql` addon, but ended with no luck.

Is the ORM suitable tool for such operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple.Data currently has no migrations feature (which is the technical name for what you're describing). I recommend using the FluentMigrations package for working with your database schema.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ProcedureWithoutParameters 
AS

CREATE TABLE Persons
(
PersonID int,
LastName varchar(255),
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255)
);
```

[documentation on stored procs](http://simplefx.org/simpledata/docs/pages/Tasks/UsingSprocs.html)